# How to update a infopath built content-type

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, content-type

With InfoPath I created a content type and saved it in a library.  Now I want to edit the infopath form and save it, but it tells me:

> The form template cannot be published to the server:
>   https://myportal.mydomain.com. Sandboxed solutions are not enabled on the
>   SharePoint server farm. To continue, contact a site collection or farm
>   administrator or publish the form template as an
>   administrator-approved form template.

Do I need to turn on Sandboxed Solutions?  I'm not sure I want to, but I do want to update my infopath content-type form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned on sandboxed solutions and after doing some other things, it worked.  However, I also deleted all the custom code, so I may not have had to turn on sandboxed solutions.

My question was whether to turn it on or not.  After some amount of research, I found that most everyone has it turned on, and it allows certain code to run in a different thread so that if it crashes it doesn't bring down the whole place.  If you don't have it enabled, you cannot run custom code in your infopath form.  The reason for the sandboxing requirement is because the infopath form runs in the browser, and Sharepoint doesn't want any malicious code (which could have been inserted by anybody who can publish infopath forms to your Sharepoint) to affect the actual server.

So, the short answer is YES, you do need to have sandboxing turned on if you are going to use custom code.

So, in order to update the content type, you just re-publish it.  If you have everything in place, it will replace the former form, and anywhere the content-type has been deployed, it will be updated.  Thus you will have achieved to update multiple instances of the form with only one edit.

However, if you have code-behind in your form, you have to [jump through some other hoops](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49320/how-to-submit-an-infopath-form-to-its-own-library/49907#49907).

Answer (score 0):

There are zillion ways how to screw things and just one or quite a few how to make them right.
Your question simply does not contain any information how to reproduce your problem.
And there is no point to guess and discuss how to screw things.

I believe the following step-by-step article should answer most of your doubts and questions about usage of Infopath form templates as content types:

- [Jo-Anne Alfafara. Side-by Side versioning with Content Types](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/jo-anne_alfafara/archive/2010/10/06/side-by-side-versioning-with-content-types2.aspx)

Comment: Well, I created an site content type using InfoPath.  Then I saved it using InfoPath into a form library.  Now I go back to InfoPath to edit the form I made there.  Now it asks me about sandboxing.  The link you point to does not say anything about sandboxing, nor does it say anything about updating a form that has already been created.  I actually followed this post which was helpful in getting where I am: http://blogs.interfacett.com/using-infopath-2010-to-create-a-custom-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010#comment-4799

Comment: You shouldn't save but publish it into a form library. I followed that article and I was not asked to sandbox the template (though I am on Office 365 aka Sharepoint Online where it is impossible to create non-sandboxed solutions). But what is the problem if you follow what is being asked and sandbox it?

Comment: Well, I've not got sandboxing enabled, and not sure if I want to.  It seems like SP is coming at me from all angles!  I just want to do one thing at a time, but every time I try to do one thing, I have to fix two other things to get it to work and then get caught in a vicious circle!  I assume it wants to sandbox because I tried to add a rule?

Comment: [Microsoft works in mysterious ways](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23980/83071.aspx) . It fears that you might create viruses for your enterprise environment using their tools, frameworks or platforms